# Electron - Why can I use require() on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using the electron framework and I noticed that I can use require() on the client side without adding anything like require.js or head.js.
Example front-end code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require("electron")
    const path = require("path")
    const url = require("url")
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron binds Node and Chromium so that you can do that. Read up on that here: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#using-nodejs-apis

Comment: The link you shared is broken. I wish you pasted the content here, instead or alongside the link

Comment: @gbenroscience copying and pasting is frowned upon. ill find a new link